# How can I make the screen not lock when I close the laptop in Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: power-management, lock-screen, lid, gnome-power-manager

I think it is annoying that I have to enter my password every time I close the lid of my computer. There was a setting *when the lid is closed: do nothing.* in earlier versions, but this feature seems to have been removed.

How do I do configure the computer to not require a password as soon as the laptop is reopened?